# How to lock (other) apps with password?

Tags: android, android-service

I've seen some "app locking" solutions in the Google Play store and I was wondering how those apps work. I'd like to build something similar.

I realize that this might require some special permission or maybe request the app to be added as device administrator.

Is there some broadcast that is triggered just before an app is launched that I can intercept and do some action (e.g. launch an activity that will request the user to fill a password)? I've read some lengthy discussions how this is not a good idea and the only idea is to have a background service that will continuously poll the running processes and check for changes, but I think retrieving this list every second and checking it for chances is not good for the battery and I think other app locking apps out there must be using a different approch.

If possible, without the need for a rooted phone.

Comment: found any solution ?

Comment: No, it seems that the current solution at the moment is to run a continuous service that checks e.g. every 1 second and gets all running apps, ordered by their backstack (usually app number one in the list is the one that is currently in the foreground). If that app is in the list of locked ones, immediately launch an activity that prompts for a password. Not the most elegant solution, nor battery sparing, but that's how all apps with this feature present in the market work at the moment.

Comment: Also worth noting that recent Android versions forbid apps from reading the full list of currently running apps, rendering the approach from my last comment useless (and in turn, all apps in the market that offer "locking" of other apps). Expect them to fail in oblivion pretty soon.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply but the issue is if i have clean master or ram cleaner app installed in my device then it may kill process in this case my service onDestroy method not called so how can i restart my service if process killed by any 3rd party ram cleaner apps

Comment: You should setup a repeating AlarmManager pending intent that starts your service every X seconds.